# MaterialTimePicker with all-day support - Android Material Components

Tags: android, datetimepicker, material-components-android, material-components, android-timepicker

Does anyone know of a fork of the material-components-android repo (or similar library) that implements an "All day" checkbox, or better yet, an All-day + time range selection feature?

Right now I am resorting to showing a few dialogs one after the other, like dateRangeDialog -> all day or set times dialog -> set start time dialog -> set end time dialog. Of course, this is not the best user experience.

If you do not know of a library, has anyone found a way to do it within MaterialTimePicker itself? I don't believe it is possible currently without changing the code.

Thanks for any help provided!